# UIPickerView is freezing the UI

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm implementing a simple picker view in Swift. Everything is wired up and here's all the code I have so far:

```
//MARK: - picker data and delegates

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 2
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return self.visableScores
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!
{
    return "\(row)"
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{

}
```

`visableScores` is an Int.

For some reason as soon as I try to scroll on the picker view the UI freezes and becomes barely responsive.  I have never used a picker view.  Am I doing something wrong or should I look elsewhere for why the UI is freezing?

Comment: That's pretty much it.  Everything on the view (a button and a UISegmentedControl) is responsive until I try to scroll through the picker view - then the whole app freezes.  It's very odd

Comment: It's not crashing, just slowing down.  picker starts to scroll, gets almost to 1 and stops.  App becomes unresponsive for long bursts - after several seconds the scrollview might scroll a little further.  If you hit the button it won't respond for several seconds or longer.  Perhaps xCode is upset that I spelled "visible" incorrectly :)

Comment: I can't right now, sorry

Comment: So I just built the sample project with just the picker view and it was still doing it.  I quit the simulator and ran the project again and it's fine.  It was the simulators fault.  GRRR!  Thanks for looking!

Comment: This can be an answer though! Helped me!

Comment: Great.  Glad it helped!  I just posted the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that the simulator just needed to be restarted.

I quit the simulator, ran the project again, and everything was back to normal.

It's happened since then and now my default action for any weird behavior is to restart Xcode and the simulator.

Comment: I have had the same issue a few times. I hope this is just a simulator bug and it's not a crash that will happen on actual devices...